# Prove that if $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and has three roots, then its derivative $f′$ has at least two roots.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I know that we are supposed to use Mean Value THeorem for this question. So from the theorem, if $f$ is continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ and has two roots, this means that there is a point $c\in [a,b]$ where $f'(x)=0.$ But is this logic correct for $3$ roots?

I am not sure if I understand how to construct a proof here.

Answer (score 6):

If $f$ is differentiable and $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = f(x_3) = 0$ with $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$ then you can apply the mean-value theorem (or [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem)) to both intervals $[x_1,x_2]$ and $[x_2, x_3]$.  It follows that $f'$ has a root in each of the open intervals $(x_1, x_2)$ and $(x_2, x_3)$. That makes (at least) two roots of the derivative.

In the same way you can show that if  $f$ has $n$ distinct roots then $f'$ has (at least) $n-1$ distinct roots.

(And if the second derivative exists, then $f''$ has at least $n-2$ roots, you get the idea?)

Comment: yes, thank you so much!